# How can I use event listeners and functions to add the key pressed to a string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a keypad on my website that accepts 6 numbers and only 6 numbers.  It should take the numbers that the user clicks and display them at the bottom, where it says "Enter Pass Code" otherwise.  I have assigned event listeners to the div elements that need them, my question lies in how I am supposed to add the numbers to the string, so that I can display them at the bottom.  Normally I use syntax like

```
var numString = "";
numString = numString + X;
```

I then add the values to numString, but in this case I am not sure what I am adding.  My code currently looks like this:

```
var numString = "";

var doSomething = function(event) {
//    console.log(event.type);
//    console.log(event.target);
//    stringCounter = stringCounter + ;
    console.log(stringCounter);
};

var doSomethingElse = function(event) {

}
let a = document.getElementById("One");

a.addEventListener(
    'click',
    doSomething,
    false
);
```

The third thing that is commented out is where my problem lies.  I am not sure what it is that I am supposed to add to the numString so that it reads any numeric keys that I click on the webpage.
The HTML for the page is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Keypad </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
          type = "text/css"
          href = "css/keypad.css" />
    <link rel="s
    stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="overall">
    <div id="accesspadtitle">
        Access Keypad
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowOne">
        <div id="One"> 1</div>
        <div id="Two"> 2</div>
        <div id="Three"> 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowTwo">
        <div id="Four"> 4</div>
        <div id="Five"> 5</div>
        <div id="Six"> 6</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowThree">
        <div id="Seven"> 7</div>
        <div id="Eight"> 8</div>
        <div id="Nine"> 9</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowFour">
        <div id="Enter"> Enter </div>
        <div id="Zero"> 0 </div>
        <div id="Clear"> Clear </div>
    </div>
    <div id="passCode">
        <p> Enter Pass Code</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="javascript/keypad.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you are making a web page, you are doing JavaScript here, not Java. They are different.

Comment: Please show the HTML for the page where this JavaScript code is being used.

Comment: `document.getElementById("passCode").innerText += whatever you want to add`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect running example.

Run the following snippet
or
JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ymuxdvfb/3/

```js
var numberOfEntries=0;
var passcode=document.querySelector(".code");
for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){
  let btn=document.createElement('button');
  btn.onclick=function(){
  addPassCode((i!=10)?i:0);
  };
  btn.className="grid-item";
  btn.innerHTML=(i!=10)?i:0;
  document.querySelector('.grid-container').appendChild(btn);
}
document.querySelector("#clear").onclick=function(){
passcode.innerHTML="";
numberOfEntries=0;
}
document.querySelector("#delete").onclick=function(){
if(passcode.innerHTML.length!=0){
passcode.innerHTML=passcode.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
numberOfEntries-=1;
}
}

function addPassCode(text){
 if(numberOfEntries==6){
 alert("Max 6 digits are allowed");
 return;
 }
 passcode.innerHTML+=text;
 numberOfEntries++;
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
</div>
<br>
Your pass code is:<span class="code"></span>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
<button id="delete">BackSpace</button>
```